# Are Geometric Translations Linear?

Tags: math, matrix

I'm studying linear algebra and I discovered that linear transformations are often used in video games.

I tried to calculate the associated matrix with the transformation that translates a point (x y z) by a vector (x y z) and I came to the conclusion that that transformation is not linear because, given p1, p2 and a translation vector v ∊ V:

```
T(v1 + v2) = v1 + v2 + p ≠ T(v1) + T(v2)
```

I navigated online and I found that 3D coordinates (x y z) are translated in a vector (x y z 1) but, given v1 and v2  ∊ V:

```
v1 + v2 = (x1 + x2, y1 + y2, z1 + z2, 2)
```

V is not even a vector space

My question is: why do I get these wrong results?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You are right, but there is a cure the keyword is "Homogeneous coordinates". Here is an introduction (from wikipedia): Jules Bloomenthal and Jon Rokne, Homogeneous coordinates: http://www.unchainedgeometry.com/jbloom/pdf/homog-coords.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In the vector with homogeneous coordinate format, (x y z 1),
(x/1 y/1 z/1) are 3D cartesian coordinates, and 1 is the scaling factor.
We divide the first three values by the scaling factor to get the vector in cartesian coordinate format, (x y z). Homogeneous coordinates can be useful for efficient arbitrary precision with rational coordinates, and eloquent algebra with nice properties like linearity here.

When we want to translate a point by adding a vector, that's natural with cartesian coordinates. With all point/vector coordinates in cartesian format,
addition of a vector, v, to a point, p1, is a translation, T1, to some point, p2, such that

> T1(p1) = p1 + v = p2

You are correct that something like T1 isn't linear.

When we want to translate a point by multiplying a matrix, it's more natural to think in homogeneous coordinates. This matrix, A, would be the identity matrix, but its last column is the vector, v, in homogeneous form. With points in homogeneous format, we can represent the transform, T2, as

> T2(p1) = A * p1 = p2

With T2, we do have a linear transform.

Answer (score 0):

Your results after not wrong: The translation of a point by a vector is not a linear transformation.

Translating a point by a vector is an *affine* transformation and it's done in an *affine space*. An affine space can be loosely defined as a set of points together with a vector space, where you can add a vector to a point and get another point as a result. Adding points to points is not allowed.

One way to construct an affine space is by taking a *projective space* whose elements are represented with *homogeneous coordinates*. These concepts come from the beautiful field of projective geometry, but a full explanation does not fit in a stack overflow post.

A more direct way to construct an affine space is by taking a vector space and adding one extra bit of information: take vectors of the form (x y z 1) as the points, and vectors of the form (x y z 0) as the vectors. Note that the points do not form a vector space, but the vectors do, and that if you add a vector to a point, the result is another point.

With this representation of points and vectors, translation of a point p by a vector can be written as a matrix multiplication T*p. The matrix T for translating by vector (x y z 0) is:

```
1 0 0 x
0 1 0 y
0 0 1 z
0 0 0 1
```

Note that this is still not a linear transform because points do not form a vector space.